# Posting List<Object> to a webapi 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a webapi as follow

```
 public OatherResponse Post([FromBody] List<Oather> oather)
 {
```

Note that `OatherResponse` and `Oather` both are classes having some property.
Now I am trying to test this using simple html as below

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:50813/api/RegisterOather">
    <input type="text" name="oather[0].OatherName" id="oather[0].OatherName" value="a3VsZGVlcA==" />
    <input type="text" name="oather[1].OatherName" id="oather[1].OatherName" value="a3VsZGVlcA==" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here" />
</form>
```

`OatherName` is a `string` property in `Oather` class. But I always get count of `oather` as zero.

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute values should be

```
name="[0].OatherName"
name="[1].OatherName"
```

Comment: It worked!! but can you explain why it worked. In normal MVC I have used and above worked.

Comment: Also when some one will consume this what he will will have to pass a list similar to oather or anything else.

Comment: No it would not have worked in 'normal' MVC. What happens is the binder initializes `List<Oather>` as the object to bind values to. Then it inspects the form values (and route values etc). The first one would have been `oather[0].OatherName` but List<T> does not contain a property named `oather` so binding fails.

Comment: RULE 1. Always use strongly typed html helpers to generate your html. RULE 2. Use `for` loops or custom `EditorTemplates` when rending html for collections